# Create Padding around a div?

Tags: html, padding

How do I create padding around a div but not pushing out the container?

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/jgGtd

I create 2divs but then when I set a padding around it the child div got push out??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div>lol</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  background:yellow;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  padding:1em;
}
div div{
 background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the normal behaviour of the default box model, i.e the padding and the border dimensions are added to the width property.

If you want to avoid clumsy calculations, you can change the default model (content-box) using `box-sizing` like so:

```
* { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

this would make the padding and border of all the elements part of the declared or inherited width and height, thus keeping your layout intact.

Now, if you were to declare a width of 100% or a 100px, and then add padding or border, it wouldn't have affected the total width, but would rather be included within the confines of the declared width.

Comment: Wrong! Opera has this: `-o-box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: Opera 8.5+ supports the non-vendor prefix version

Comment: Then what about the befores?

Answer (score 3):

Padding is in the inside of the elements.  I believe you want to use margin here, which is outside of block elements:

```
div{
  background:yellow;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:1em;
}
div div{
  margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This (Values can be changed based on what you are doing). I credit SoloLearn for helping me learn it (the app is Learn HTML for android).

`<div width:100%;height:100%; style="background-color:white; color:black; padding:20px;">`

Width and height auto fit themselves, background colors make box color, color is text color, and padding adds space after content. You can also nest  tags if you want to change padding color since there is no value or element that I know of to do it inside of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheat, but it works when you just need some html to get the edges of the text in a few spaces:

div style="padding-left: 4em; padding-right: 4em"